# How to Send data to a php page from iPad?

Tags: php, objective-c, ipad

I want to send some data to my php page, php page is located into a different system and I want to call that page from my iPad app....how can I make this connection so that I can call php page from my app and what will be the connection string for it..Kindly describe in detail. Thanks in advance

Comment: what kind of php page it is? can u open it in your browser? is it a service?

Comment: through ip address you can connect the localhost

Comment: How about reading the documentation of NSURL?

Comment: CRDave, its a simple php page which recieve data by $_POST.

Comment: laxoline, I have used the ip but no result was found...instead its not  able to connect with page

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041271/how-to-send-data-to-a-php-page-from-ipad/14041494#14041494

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+post+http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to diagnose the problem by taking the following steps:

1) Make sure that your iPad and located system are connected with same network.

2) Get IP address from located system **(eg IP :121.127.1.4)**

[image]

3) And try this following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://121.127.1.4/webservices.php"];


NSData *postDatastr = [NSData dataWithBytes:[postStr UTF8String] length:[postStr length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString: SignUpConnection_server]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postDatastr];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// Create Connection.
NSURLConnection  *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (conn) {
    resposeData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}
else
{
    NSLog( @"Data could not be received from: %@", request.URL );
}
```

Comment: my page is located in a xamp htdocs folder so what will be url for it? Should I not need to mention the localhost in url?

Comment: first u try with Ipad safari browser eg: http://121.127.1.4. before the make sure that you iPad & local system are connected with same n/w

Comment: suppose if my file is in my desktop pc...and i am calling it from my mac saffari, so i will wrote this http://121.127.1.4///localhost/webservices.php  write?

Comment: Yes, instead of localhost try http://121.127.1.4/webservices.php

Comment: Ohh thank you so much laxoline....It solved my problem...once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use native ios app you should use web-service for that.

Comment: why that? you can easily create post requests for an language, including objective-c. there is no need to break the user experience.

Comment: I did not understand. Basically there are communication layer (web service api) between ios native app and backend db.